# assigning variable value using return

Tags: swift

I've stumbled upon some code where the variable declarations use `return` to assign the variable value like below:

```
var method: HTTPMethod { return .Post}
```

Is the line above the same as below?

```
var method: HTTPMethod = .Post
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two lines are not so similar.

The first line declares a computed property without the setter. This means that the value is constant.

The second declaration is a simple property declaration with the value initialised to `.Post`. This means that the property can be changed later on.

The first line is more similar to the following line than to your second line:

```
let method: HTTPMethod = .Post
```

Since the above also declares a constant property.

Then what's the difference between a `let` constant property and a computed property without a setter and returns a constant value? The main difference is that a computed property can be put into extensions while `let` constants cannot.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "can be put into extensions"

Comment: @Brosef extensions can only contain computed properties and methods, not stored properties. If you try to put a let constant into an extension, it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

No both are different

This one is get-only property

```
var method: HTTPMethod { return .Post}
```

and second one is mutable object where you can assign different
value.

```
var method: HTTPMethod = .Post
```

Comment: I understood in few Seconds. !

Answer (score 0):

```
var method: HTTPMethod = .Post
```

The latter can be mutated if you change `var` to `let` the behavior would be the same as the first option.